# Interacting with ajax response items

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using codeIgniter for building a web application.

I currently have a controller that loads an index action, and an index view.

Inside this view, i use ajax to call another controller action, and fetch items from a database, i load them into a div.

What would be the approach to being able to interact with these objects, by, let's say Jquery on click events.

```
$("#other").click(function() {
 $("#target").click();
});
```

The above obviously doesn't work.

I can't figure out how to do this with ajax calls, because they load after the dom is ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to delegate the dynamically generated elements to there closest static parent using `on`...

here i am using `document` as parent.. but it is recommended to use the closest static parent which is present when element is appended.. and `trigger()`` to trigger the click

```
$(document).on('click',"#other",function() {
    $("#target").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **.trigger** like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#other").click(function() {
        $("#target").trigger('click');
    });
})
```

Comment: You have to also add above all $(document).ready(function () { .. your code.. });

Comment: Ofcourse @Ali,we hope that is already under the document.ready(){---}

Comment: Ok let me add it also,for your sake